# Why colorBlendFactor does not affect 'SKLabelNode' on my device in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, device, sklabelnode, color-blending

I'm trying to change color on `SKLabelNode` in my project.

When I run the project on iPhone 5s with *iOS 11.1.2* the `SKLabelNode` have the correct color, but when I run the project on iPad with *iOS 9.3.5*
the `SKLabelNode` appears in white.

Here is how I color the label:

`roundLabel.colorBlendFactor = 1.0 
roundLabel.color = UIColor.red`

** on *iPad Pro* simulator the color is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloring the `.fontColor` instead of the `.color` solved the problem!

`roundLabel.fontColor = UIColor.red`

works!